# Transformations being one to one

Tags: linear-algebra

So I need help determining if I have the concepts down.  If a matrix of a transformation is invertible that means it is onto and one to one right?  Maybe help me with a simple example.  Can I just see if the determinate is equal to 0 and if it isint that means it is invertible and one to one and onto?  I kind of understand the concept just the application of it is tripping me up.

Comment: As long as your matrix has elements in a field

Comment: It would be useful to review the invertible matrix theorem, which lists various equivalent statements of an invertible matrix. Find your own way of showing the chain of equivalences.

Answer (score 1):

If a transformation matrix is invertible, it's onto and one to one, yes. But if the *determinant* equals 0, then the matrix isn't invertible and hence not bijective.

As far as your story tells, I think you understood most.

Comment: Ok.  I was also just curious when it says you have a transformation of say R^2 to R^3 that represents that you are going from 2 rows to a 3 column matrix through the transformation correct?  How can you tell what a matrix is going to transform into?

Comment: You can't, it depends on your transformation function.

Comment: Ok.  well I just watched a video and the professor said if you put the matrix into REF and if it had a pivot in every row it would be one to one.  He then said it was the same way for onto: if there is a pivot in every column it is onto... But then there are some instances with onto and not one to one?  it wouldn't make since if so because if there was a pivot in every row it would always be one to one and onto.  follow me?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you mean, but i think it makes sense, because the fact every column contains a pivot implies you can row reduce nicely, which implies invertibility and thus onto and one to one.

Answer (score 0):

Invertibility is equivalent to 1-1 and onto. You need 1-1, so that the inverse knows where to send the elements. For instance if $Tx=y$ and $Tz=y,$ then the inverse can't tell if it should send $y$ to $x$ or $z.$ If it isn't onto, then there is some point in the range space which has no preimage, so it's hard to think of a good way for the inverse to act on that point. If the matrix is square, then you can use the determinant test, just like you said.
I'd be glad to provide an example if you let me know what kinds of things have tripped you up. Are they throwing tricky examples at you and asking if it's invertible? If so, what kinds of examples?

Comment: Ok.  I was also just curious when it says you have a transformation of say R^2 to R^3 that represents that you are going from 2 rows to a 3 column matrix through the transformation correct?  How can you tell what a matrix is going to transform into?